# How can I decrypt a variable within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, encryption, foreach

The following code loops my decryption I have no idea how to decrypt each inner['post_text'].

https://gyazo.com/672cd615b86b3c107da7e2c386d3b2f9

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['room_id'])) {
    $getPosts = $verbinding->prepare("SELECT user_name, post_text FROM posts WHERE room_id = :room_id");
    $getPosts->bindParam(':room_id', $_SESSION['room_id']);
    $getPosts->execute();
    $posts = $getPosts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($posts as $inner) {
        $username = $inner['user_name'];
        $text = $inner['post_text'];
        $um = "@4um:~$";
        echo "<br><div class = \"posts\">" . $username . "$um&nbsp" . decr($text) . " </div>";
    }

}

function decr($text){
    $iterations = 1;
    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $text = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $text, $salt, $iterations, 512);
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: sensible code indentation makes code more readable and most importantly **easier to debug**

Comment: thanks I was clear till I copy pasted it. Will try harder to make everything look clean next times

Comment: change the decrypt function to return the text, not echo it and call it in the foreach that is parsing data from the database. `$text = decr($inner['post_text']);`

Comment: It appears you are trying to decrypt a HASH and that is not possible. _Its not an encryption for a start_  Also note in the [manual page for `hash_pbkdf2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) It suggests [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) Is a much better mechanism for hashing password. Although this does not look like you are hashing passwords

Comment: **You cannot UNHASH a HASH** You can only hash another piece of text in the same way with the same salt and then compare your stored hash with the new hash to see if they are the same. Therefore saying the the new piece of plain text was the same as the original text that you hashed and stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments you cannot decrypt a hash. For that you need to use an encryption algorithm, using `mcrypt_encrypt()` before saving and `mcrypt_decrypt()` when displaying.

Seeing as you've already hashed your content, there is no way to get it back. You need to start over, and delete all of the old content, in order to do what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return an variable `$text` instead of echo in `decr()` function

```
function decr($text){
    $iterations = 1;
    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $text = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $text, $salt, $iterations, 512);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Except that the function itself is not achieving what the OP actually wants. You cannot decrypt a HASH. ___Certainly not by re-hashing the hash___ And certainly not by using a brand new salt. Whole function is I am afraid nonsence

Comment: @4um You cannot UNHASH a HASH. Tell us what you are actually trying to achieve and we will try and put you back on track

Comment: Yeah I just read your comments, I saved the $text in the database encrypted with the same method I used to decrypt it. I basically want to built an own encrypted chat site

Comment: @4um the method works, but it does not do what you think, RiggFolly is wright. Is the '$input['post_text']' a password in the database? Or it should be encoded text (not encrypted).

Comment: SHA512 is one way encryption only.

Comment: @mi it is an encrypted text message. the password encryption is already fully working.

Comment: You will need to use an ENCRYPTION method and not a HASH

Comment: @4um Its NOT encrypted, its HASHED. HASHING is a one way process. It is not an encryption mechanism

Comment: @M.I. so i will have to look into other types of encryption, thanks for the help will look further into encryptions!

Comment: encryption =/= hashing will remember this thanks learned a lot

Comment: Yes. @RiggsFolly is wright again, that is the big difference between HASH and encryption, the first is one way only, the second could be decrypted.